# volatile in double-checked locking in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

As I understand, this is a correct implementation of the double-checked locking pattern in Java (since Java 5):

```
class Foo {
    private volatile Bar _barInstance;
    public Bar getBar() {
        if (_barInstance == null) {
            synchronized(this) { // or synchronized(someLock)
                if (_barInstance == null) {
                    Bar newInstance = new Bar();
                    // possible additional initialization
                    _barInstance = newInstance;
                }
            }
        }
        return _barInstance;
    }
}
```

I wonder if absence of `volatile` is a serious error or just a slight imperfection with possible performance drawback assuming `_barInstance` accessed only through `getBar`.

My idea is the following: `synchronized` introduces *happens-before* relation. The thread that initializes `_barInstance` writes its value to the main memory leaving the synchronized block. So there will be no double initialization of `_barInstance` even when it isn't `volatile`: other threads have `null` in theirs local copies of `_barInstance` (get `true` in the first check), but have to read the new value from the main memory in the second check after entering the synchronized block (get `false` and do no re-initialization). So the only problem is an excessive one-per-thread lock acquisition.

As I understand, it's correct in CLR and I believe it's also correct in JVM. Am I right?

Thank you.

Comment: @Todd possibly, but there are only *"```volatile``` is important"* and *"not thread safe"* in answers without explanation. I really want to understand this case in details :)

Comment: Sigh. [Read](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/05/double-checked-locking.html) [Jeremy](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html) [Manson](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2007/05/double-checked-locking-and-problem-with.html).

Comment: @DavidConrad thank you, probably I understand. JVM can reorder constructor instructions to be performed after the assignment of ```_barInstance``` and the following threads could see ```_barInstance``` as initialized before it actually is. When they see it isn't ```null``` they don't acquire the lock and *happens-before*... well not happens :) And they carry on with not-initialized object. On the other hand, when ```_barInstance``` is ```volatile``` *happens-before* write and reads always holds. Correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not using volatile may result in errors in the following case:

- Thread 1 enters `getBar()` and finds `_barInstance` to be `null`
- Thread 1 attempts to create a `Bar` object and update the reference to `_barInstance`. Due to certain compiler optimisations, these operations may be done out of order.
- Meanwhile, thread 2 enters `getBar()` and sees a non-null `_barInstance` but might see default values in member fields of the `_barInstance` object. It essentially sees a partially constructed object but the reference is not null.

The `volatile` modifier will prohibit a write or read of the variable `_barInstance` with respect to any previous read or write. Hence, it will make sure that thread 2 will not see a partially constructed object.

For more details: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html